# comparing two dataframes and finding a unique combbination of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames with different size and different number of column, for example:

```
DF1:
index  col1  col2  col3 
 1      AA    A12  SH7B
 2      Ac    DJS  283
 3      ZH    28S  48d

DF2:
index  col1  col2    col3    col4
 2      AA    cc2    SH7B    hd5
 7      Ac    DJS  283,dhb   re
 10     ZH    28S  SJE,48d   385d
 23    3V4    38D  350,eh4   sm4
 44     S3    3YE  032,she   3927
```

so the indexes are different. and there are some unique combination of data in the first dataframe which is similar to other dataframe and I want to find them.So I want to iterate through the rows of second dataframe and find every single combination of data per row (for example: (7,Ac,DJS,283,re) and (7,Ac,DJS,dhb,re) are two combinations of index 7 since there is a column that has more than one value) and compare it with the first dataframe's rows and print it out if there is an identical combination in second dataframe as well.

```
result: 
 1      Ac    DJS  283
 2     ZH    28S  48d
```

thank you

Comment: Define "similar." Unless there is a formal definition of similarity, you problem cannot be solved algorithmically.

Comment: I explained in the example, by similar i mean identical...for example the combination of (Ac,DJS,283) can be find in both dataframes so this is one of the rows of result dataframe

Comment: But there is no `283` in the second table. There is `283,dhb` instead.

Comment: yes, so i want to iterate though that column that has more than one value, then find each combination of data, then compare ir with the second dataframe, if for each combination in first dataframe there is an identical row in second dataframe, print it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to *split* the *col3* from data frame 2 firstly, and then merge it back with data frame 1; To split *col3* of data frame 2, a common approach is to split and flatten the col3 while use `numpy.repeat` to make equal length of other columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

# count how many repeats are needed for other columns based on commas
repeats = df2.col3.str.count(",") + 1        

# repeat columns except for col3, split and flatten col3 and merge it back with df1
(df2.drop('col3', 1).apply(lambda col: np.repeat(col, repeats))
 .assign(col3 = list(chain.from_iterable(df2['col3'].str.split(','))))
 .merge(df1))

# col1  col2    col4    col3
#0  Ac   DJS      re     283
#1  ZH   28S    385d     48d
```

Comment: thank you, i'm getting this error: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'"

Comment: Not exactly sure what is happening, you can try to cast the data frame to str type. `df1 = df1.astype(str); df2 = df2.astype(str)`.